# how to insert video in to android studio?

Tags: java, android

so far i go with this but  when i run my program in android studio and i clicked the button keep showing cant play video why?

```
package a0.insertvideo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button clk;
VideoView videov;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    clk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    videov =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
}

public void videoplay(View v){
    String videopath = 
"android.resource://a0.insertvideo/"+R.raw.samplevideo_1280x720_2mb ;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath); 
    videov.setVideoURI(uri);
    videov.start();
// a0.mcqwithvideo is my package use own package to play video right

}
}
```

Comment: create raw folder in res/ and put you videos raw folder

Comment: i done that all but still the same show cant play video.

Comment: try bellow answer

Comment: still the same.

Comment: ca you pur error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public void videoplay(View v){
String videopath = 
"android.resource://a0.insertvideo/"+R.raw.samplevideo_1280x720_2mb + ".mp4";  // if your video is not .mp4 change it your video extension 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath); 
videov.setVideoURI(uri);
videov.start();
// a0.mcqwithvideo is my package use own package to play video right

}
}
```